# Unable to get FAN test ads in Mopub Android

Tags: android, twitter-fabric, mopub, facebook-audience-network, native-ads

I am integrating Facebook Ads with Mopub in android. I implement code as per documentation of Mopub to integrate Native ads into RecyclerView. But Ads are not displaying in RecyclerView.

Below Error are shown in Logcat.

> D/FBAudienceNetworkLog: Audience Network Loaded (displayed for test
>   ads only)
>
> V/MoPub: Native Ad failed to load with error: A required
>   renderer was not registered for the CustomEventNative..
>
> Native ad request failed.
>                                                          com.mopub.network.MoPubNetworkError: No ads found for ad unit.
>                                                              at com.mopub.network.AdRequest.parseNetworkResponse(AdRequest.java:140)
>                                                              at com.mopub.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:123)

Answer (score 0):

I do wrong with Adapter. 
Below is right setup for Adapter.

```
ViewBinder viewBinder = new ViewBinder.Builder(R.layout.my_ad_view)
                                    .titleId(R.id.native_title)
                                    .textId(R.id.native_text)
                                    .mainImageId(R.id.native_main_image)
                                    .iconImageId(R.id.native_icon_image)
                                    .privacyInformationIconImageId(R.id.native_privacy_information_icon_image)
                                    .callToActionId(R.id.native_cta)
                                    .build();

//                            FacebookAdRenderer renderer = new FacebookAdRenderer(viewBinder);

                            adAdapter.registerAdRenderer(new MoPubStaticNativeAdRenderer(viewBinder));
                            RequestParameters parameters = new RequestParameters.Builder().build();

                            adAdapter.loadAds(Constants.AD_ID, parameters);

                            mList.setAdapter(adAdapter);
```

I was register FacebookAdRenderer instance for render ads instead of MoPubStaticNativeAdRenderer

```
 adAdapter.registerAdRenderer(new MoPubStaticNativeAdRenderer(viewBinder));
```

Comment: I have followed the above implementation for native ads and am seeing  the test ad unit id _11a17b188668469fb0412708c3d16813_ successfully. However, I am not seeing live Facebook ads when using the created ad unit id. @AmmY, how many requests / users did you have before seeing live ads from FAN?

Comment: I don't know exactly. That was my old project.

Comment: All good. I figured out I wasn't implementing the custom Facebook Ad Renderer.